# Função dias Excel Datas não funciona

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft

Não sei o que fazer, o excel não me mostra o resultado correto na formula de data abaixo, o resultado esperado deveria ser 30 dias, mas aparece 30/01/1900
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Deu boa, muito obrigado. Coloca como resposta !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente alterar o formato da célula Duração de Data para Número, pois o resultado de número `30` em formato de Data são 30 dias após a primeira data que o Excel aceita (que é 01/01/1900), portanto, é dia `30/01/1900`.

E as datas `E2` e `F2`, em formato de número são: `42826` e `42856`, respectivamente.

Por exemplo, com a formatação como número as células ficam assim:

[image: Número]

E como datas, assim:

[image: Data]