# Formato de data em fração

Tags: microsoft-excel, concatenação-de-string, fórmula

Estou com seguinte valor `14/02/2018 13:53:12` em excel.

Célula com o valor está no formato texto.

Quando tendo concatenar o valor a data acima fica assim: `43145,57861111111`

Alguém sabe como resolver?

A função que estou usando é assim: `=CONCATENAR("Codigo: ";A1;" - Data: ";B1)`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Função dias Excel Datas não funciona](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/243581/fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-dias-excel-datas-n%c3%a3o-funciona)

Comment: Tente colocar no formato `Data`

Comment: Nada. Ainda não funcionou

Comment: Edite a pergunta com a fórmula que está usando para concatenar, na coluna `D`

Comment: Editei a pergunta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você deve converter para texto utilizando a função TEXTO, veja abaixo:

```
=CONCATENAR("Codigo: ";A1;" - Data: ";TEXTO(B1;"dd/MM/aaaa HH:mm"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Com os dados:

```
+---+---------+-------------+
|   |    A    |      B      |
+---+---------+-------------+
| 1 | 9630638 | 43145,57861 |
+---+---------+-------------+
```

Com a fórmula de concatenar `=CONCATENAR("Codigo: ";A1;" - Data: ";B1)` o resultado é `Codigo: 9630638 - Data: 43145,5786111111`

Isso ocorre porque o Excel está utilizando o dado da célula `B1`como número, então basta convertê-la para o formato data para obter a data: `=TEXTO(B1;"dd/mm/aaaa hh:mm:ss")`

Então você pode concatenar com esta fórmula: `=CONCATENAR("Codigo: ";A1;" - Data: ";TEXTO(B1;"dd/mm/aaaa hh:mm:ss"))`

E o resultado é: `Codigo: 9630638 - Data: 14/02/2018 13:53:12`